# Selection sort: What is n-1?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

```
int main() { 
    int arr[] = { 64, 25, 12, 22, 11 }; 
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); 
    
    selectionSort(arr, n); 
   
    return 0;  
}

void selectionSort(int arr[], int n) { 
    int i, j, min_idx; 
  
    // One by one move boundary of unsorted subarray 
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) { 
        // Find the minimum element in unsorted array 
        min_idx = i; 
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) 
            if (arr[j] < arr[min_idx]) 
                min_idx = j; 
  
        // Swap the found minimum element with the first element 
        swap(&arr[min_idx], &arr[i]); 
    } 
}
```

I have see this C language code that'll do sorting algorithms called Selection Sort. But my question is in the `selectionSort` function.

Why in the first `for` loop, is the condition `i < n - 1` whereas in the second loop it is `j < n`?

What will `i < n - 1` do exactly? and why different cases for the second loop? Can you please explain this code to me like I'm in sixth grade of elementary school. Thank You.

Comment: If `i` went up to `n`, what would you compare it to when there’s nothing after it to compare to?

Answer (score 2):

The first loop has to iterate up to index `n-2` (thus `i < n-1`) because the second for loop has to check numbers i+1 up to `n-1` (thus `j < n`). If `i` could get the value `n - 1`, then the access in `if (arr[j] < arr[min_idx])` would be out of bounds, specifically `arr[j]` would be out of bounds for `j==n`.

You could think that this implementation of selection sort moves from left to right on the array, leaving always a sorted array on its left. That's why the second for loop starts visiting elements from index `i+1`.

You could find many resources online to visualize how selection sort works, e.g., [Selection sort in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#/media/File:Selection-Sort-Animation.gif)

Answer (score 0):

The [implementation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Implementations) is annotated and explains it.

```
/* advance the position through the entire array */
/*   (could do i < aLength-1 because single element is also min element) */
for (i = 0; i < aLength-1; i++)
```

Selection sort works by finding the smallest element and swapping it in place. When there's only one unsorted element left it is the smallest unsorted element and it is at the end of the sorted array.

For example, let's say we have `{3, 5, 1}`.

```
i = 0 {3, 5, 1}  // swap 3 and 1
       ^
i = 1 {1, 5, 3}  // swap 5 and 3
          ^
i = 2 {1, 3, 5}  // swap 5 and... 5?
             ^
```

For three elements we only need two swaps. For n elements we only need n-1 swaps.

It's an optimization which might improve performance a bit on very small arrays, but otherwise inconsequential in an O(n^2) algorithm like selection sort.

Answer (score 0):

> Why in the first **for loop**, the condition is **i < n-1**? But in the second loop is **j < n**?

The loop condition for the inner loop is `j < n` because the index of the last element to be sorted is `n - 1`, so that when `j >= n` we know that it is past the end of the data.

The loop condition for the outer loop *could have been* `i < n`, but observe that no useful work would then be done on the iteration when `i` took the value `n - 1`.  The initial value of `j` in the inner loop is `i + 1`, which in that case would be `n`.  Thus no iterations of the inner loop would be performed.

But no useful work is not the same as no work at all.  On every outer-loop iteration in which `i` took the value `n - 1`, some bookkeeping would be performed, and `arr[i]` would be swapped with itself.  Stopping the outer loop one iteration sooner avoids that guaranteed-useless extra work.

All of this is directly related to the fact that no work needs to be expended to sort a one-element array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic of these nested loops:

- for each position `i` in the array

  - find the smallest element of the slice starting at this position extending to the end of the array
  - swap the smallest element and the element at position `i`

The smallest element of the 1 element slice at the end of the array is obviously already in place, so there is no need to run the last iteration of the outer loop. That's the reason for the outer loop to have a test `i < n - 1`.

Note however that there is a nasty pitfall in this test: if instead of `int` we use `size_t` for the type of the index and count of elements in the array, which is more correct as arrays can have more elements nowadays than the range of type `int`, `i < n - 1` would be true for `i = 0` and `n = 0` because `n - 1` is not negative but the largest `size_t` value which is huge. In other words, the code would crash on an empty array.

It would be safer to write:

```
    for (i = 0; i + 1 < n; i++) { ...
```